# Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Tags: dom, xampp, php, wampserver

I was using this piece of php script in a application running under over XAMPP on my local machine:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$filename = "library.xml";

if (!$dom->load($filename))
    die("Could not parse iTunes XML file: ".$filename);
```

Then i tried to move this application to a WampServer without success, with the following warning:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "file:///C:/wamp/www/parser/library.xml" in C:\wamp\www\parser\includes\libs\itunes_xml_parser.lib.php on line 111
```

This line in the error is exactly the load line, which worked flawlessly in earlier versions of XAMPP and isn't working now on XAMPP 1.7.7

Comment: Because the OP has declared that they misspelled the filename (see the comment under the accepted answer), this question is Off-topic: Typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39823) why don't you try using an absolute path for your filepath.

Also i see that this php file is located at `C:\wamp\www\parser\includes\libs` and library.xml is being searched at `C:/wamp/www/parser/`. Is this correct?

It could also be possible that you had turned off warnings/errors in your earlier xampp installation.So check [this](http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/4138324.htm) also.

Comment: My fault... i've mistaken the filename... as my pc has an xml reader setting as default, the filename was spelled "library.xml.xml" X_x