# PHP:DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Tags: php

```
class restRendering
{
    public $RestUrl='http://www.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx?uac=AnwWoM6K2.&output=xml&query=10591';
    public $XSLTPath="receipe.xsl";

    //setter method for test url

        public function setRestUrl( $value )  
        {  
            $this->RestUrl = $value;  
        }  
        public function setXSLTPath( $value ) 
        {
            $this->XSLTPath = $value;  
        }

        //It renders the iframe with base url and path.
        public function render(){
             //load the XML 
                  $xml_Doc = new DOMDocument();

                  if($xml_Doc->load($this->RestUrl))
                  {
                          //load the XSL 
                          $xsl= new DOMDocument();
                          $xsl->load($this->XSLTPath) or die("can not load  XSLT file"); 

                         $xslt = new XSLTProcessor($xsl);
                         $xslt->importStyleSheet($xsl);

                            print $xslt->transformToXML( $xml_Doc ) or die("Trasform Error");
                    }
                else{
                        echo "Can not load the url";
                    } 


        }   //End of Render method.

}
```

While executing I am getting this error:

> Warning: DOMDocument::load(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in D:\xampp\htdocs\sweet\restRendering.php on line 25
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::load(http://www.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx?uac=AnwWoM6K2.&output=xml&query=10591): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in D:\xampp\htdocs\sweet\restRendering.php on line 25
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://www.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx?uac=AnwWoM6K2.&output=xml&query=10591" in D:\xampp\htdocs\sweet\restRendering.php on line 25

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112482/warning-domdocumentload-domdocument-load-i-o-warning-failed-to-load-ex

Comment: @DainisAbols not duplicate of link provided - this one has to do with remote url

Comment: @IvanHušnjak well, it is a duplicate in case of the entity error. it's not a dupe of the DNS issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to this error:

> Warning: DOMDocument::load(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in D:\xampp\htdocs\sweet\restRendering.php on line 25

your server has a problem with DNS. It can't connect to `www.myweather2.com` because it can't translate it to an IP address.

Try

```
nslookup www.myweather2.com
```

and see what the results are. When you solve that problem, your script will probably work.